# Target multiple id's with :target?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Currently i use `<a href="id1"></a>` with CSS :target to target the specific tag.
Is it possible to target multiple tags at the same time?
So that #id1 and id2 would be in target at the same time, eexample. ..index.html#id1#id2 (or something like this?)

Comment: `:target` references the element by its `id` attribute, not the `href`, and `id` must be unique. There is also only one fragment identifier and it does not support multiple values.

Comment: I don't think you're describing :target correctly.  http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: I was. Still, I have improved the comment.

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is maybe with javascript and some wizardry.

Comment: @bmasterson I think I came up with what he is looking for. He was just asking the wrong question.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Did you resolve your issue another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :target selector to stylize multiple elements when you combine it with either a tag style or a class style.

[Like this on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/864Gv/2/):

```
HTML
<p><a href="#targetLink">Jump to New content 1</a></p>

<div id="targetLink">
    <p>New content 1...</p>
    <p>New content 2...</p>
</div>

CSS
:target p
{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

Make a div or span your id target then use the target selector in combination with an element. The effect is that all `<p>` inside of the element with `id="targetLink"` will be  given the style.

Get more control with classes [like this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/864Gv/3/):

```
HTML
<p><a href="#targetLink">Jump to New content 1</a></p>

<div id="targetLink">
    <p class="here">New content 1...</p>
    <p class="here">New content 2...</p>
    <p>New content 3...</p>
</div>

CSS
:target .here
{
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

Again, make a div or span your id target then use the target selector in combination with a a class. The effect is that all all elements with `class="here"` inside of the element with `id="targetLink"` will be given the style.

---

Here is [a neat tutorial to get a yellow fade using this technique](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/stay-on-target).